# deezer android api redirect to a blank page after submit login

Tags: android, deezer

I have an android app that uses deezer android sdk to login in that service. I never had problem to login using that api, but yesterday after submit login and password in the application it redirect me to a a blank page and not complete the autentication on deezer service.

I already tried to login on app "Deezer SDK Sample" available in developers.deezer.com and it has the same problem.

Comment: you need to put some of your code snippets so that we could looks at it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That was bug on our side for a few hours, this is fixed now.

Comment: Julaie can you checked again?it  still persists. also, there's another error for songs that ends before the "duration" time (seconds). can you check it out please? thanks in advance